# Eyebrows not fully rotating with head

Tags: bones, weight-painting, rigify, axis

The eyebrows and the rest of the body is one object. The eyebrows, eyelashes and eyes are not connected to the body. The eyebrows is the only part that doesn't fully rotate with the head when moving the head bone, where the eyes and eyelashes does, even though the eyelashes is fully weighted on the head bone like the other loose meshes. It seems like the eyebrows rotates around a different axis as the head when moving the head. This only happens with the head bone, the eyebrows rotates perfectly with the neck bones. I used rigify. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated!

The head bone I mention is "spine.006" in the blend file.

[image]

[File on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l37GxB6ST32zWst_ou-9Qx72uCsumv2T/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: select them in Edit mode, in the vertex groups list click on Remove From All Groups, then select the group to which they are supposed to be part of and click on Assign

Comment: Hey. I did what you said, but unfortunately it doesn't fix it.

Comment: yes it fixes it, select the eyebrows, on the right of the Vertex Groups list there's a dropdown menu > Remove From All Groups, then assign to the group called spine.006

Comment: Thank you. My problem is fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

Select the eyebrows, on the right of the *Vertex Groups* list there's a dropdown menu, click on *Remove From All Groups*, then assign to the group called *spine.006*.